# 1.20 (b) Baby Rudin: $y-x>0 \rightarrow \exists n \, n(y-x)>1$ short question

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I found the following in Baby Rudin:

> **Theorem**
>
> If $x,y\in \Bbb R, x>0$ then there exists a natural number $n$ such that
>   $$nx>y$$

After this, he proves another theorem using the following

> Let $x<y$, we have $y-x>0$ then the theorem above yields that a natural number $n$ exists such that
>   $$
> n(y-x)>1
> $$

I'm not sure how that theorem gives that result, could someone explain this? I'm pretty  sure it must be really simple, but I'm not getting it.

E: I said in the comments this was not a duplicate to the suggested question. My doubt here was even more elementary than that question's.

Comment: The $y - x$ is the "$x$" and 1 is the "$y$"

Comment: @AngeloMark It's not a duplicate of that! I'm asking a question about the same theorem but different parts.

Comment: @Nitin Oh... Thanks. I'm really slow. You should post that as an answer haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per OP's suggestion,

> The $y - x$ is the "$x$" and 1 is the "$y$"

Comment: Indeed, the OP asked to post this as an answer. So ok.